# Running headless chrome on Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, headless, headless-browser, webpagetest

I am trying to run headless Chrome using the following command on Ubuntu.

`sudo  -u test xvfb-run --server-args='-screen 0, 1024x768x16' google-chrome -start-maximized --disable-fre --enable-benchmarking --metrics-recording-only --remote-debugging-port=1234 > /dev/null &`

Upon doing, `ps -ef | grep Chrome` I get

```
test  17671 17670  0 15:49 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/xvfb-run --server-args=-screen 0, 1024x768x16 google-chrome -start-maximized --disable-fre --enable-benchmarking --metrics-recording-only --remote-debugging-port=1234
test  17691 17671  0 15:49 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/bin/google-chrome -start-maximized --disable-fre --enable-benchmarking --metrics-recording-only --remote-debugging-port=1234
test  17694 17691  0 15:49 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/bin/google-chrome -start-maximized --disable-fre --enable-benchmarking --metrics-recording-only --remote-debugging-port=1234
test  17696     1  0 15:49 pts/0    00:00:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote
```

But I keep getting the error

```
Error: Connect DevTools
Wait timed out after 10094ms
```

Why is Devtools not up in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You should run Headless Chrome like this:

```
chrome \
  --headless \                   # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
  --disable-gpu \                # Temporarily needed if running on Windows.
  --remote-debugging-port=9222 \
  https://www.chromestatus.com   # URL to open. Defaults to about:blank.
```

Take a look at [Getting Start](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)